# many foreign keys in one table sqlite

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I want to use many foreign keys in one table on sqlite. 
But it makes just one. how can I do it?

```
CREATE TABLE STORES(
  SId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
  SName TEXT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE CITY(
  CId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
  CName TEXT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS(
  PId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
  PName TEXT NOT NULL, 
  Price REAL NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE STORE_CITY(
  CId INTEGER REFERENCES CITY(CId) NOT NULL, 
  SId INTEGER REFERENCES STORES(SId) NOT NULL, 
  PId INTEGER REFERENCES PRODUCTS(PId)
)
```

Comment: [Works for me](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/8c442/3). What exactly is the problem?

Comment: It must works. But on sqlite manager, i can't use many foreign keys.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in SQLite Manager? What error do you get?

Comment: i created tables and i want to edit coloumns for foreign keys. i have 3 cloumns in one table and all of them must be foreign keys. i made one foreign key, when i try to do it to another column, first foreign key changed as a normal coloumn by itself. (sorry my english is not perfect. i hope, i could explain)

Comment: I edited my answer to suit your problem since I can read your code now.

Comment: please post your solution so that it can help others.

Comment: i was trying create table without code and it didn't let me to make many foreign keys. i just executed my sql codes and for now, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Define the columns first, THEN make them foreign keys.

```
CREATE TABLE STORE_CITY(
  CId INTEGER,
  SId INTEGER,
  PId INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY (CId) REFERENCES CITY(CId) NOT NULL, 
  FOREIGN KEY (SId) REFERENCES STORES(SId) NOT NULL, 
  FOREIGN KEY (PId) REFERENCES PRODUCTS(PId)
)
```

Comment: This is not valid SQL.

Comment: This still is not valid SQL.

Comment: What am  I doing wrong?  I'm in the middle of something and can't test myself.

Comment: I was forgetting my brackets, wasn't I?